# Login com níveis Java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de login, só que estou com duvida como posso deixa ele com níveis/tipos (admin, usuário, cliente).

---

**IMPORTANTE :** Estou fazendo um método que use Taglib - "C:if", para fazer um Switch Case.

A ideia é fazer um redir para o admin e outro para o user

Sendo:

Admin = 0

User = 1

Algo assim:

```
if(user.getNivelAcesso()!=null){
                String nivel = user.getNivelAcesso();
                switch(nivel){
                    case "admin":
                        redir = "/admin/home.jsp";
                        break;
                    case "user":
                        redir = "/user/home.jsp";
                        break;
                    default:
                        redir = "login.jsp";
                        break;
                }
```

Assim não preciso nem usar FK, e simplifico, pois não necessito de tanta segurança assim, só preciso de um controle basico

---

Aqui está meu código MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_usuario (
  id_usuario INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  senha VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario));
```

Aqui está meu java .model:

```
public class Usuario {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String senha;


    public Usuario() {
        super();

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

Minha interface .dao Usuario.DAO:

```
public interface UsuarioDAO {
    public Usuario buscarUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException;

    public List<Usuario> listaUsuario() throws SQLException;

    public List<Usuario> pesquisarUsuario(String nome) throws SQLException;

    public boolean adicionarUsuario (Usuario usuario) throws SQLException;

    public boolean alterarUsuario (Usuario usuario) throws SQLException;

    public Usuario buscarUsuarioPorId (int idUsuario) throws SQLException;

    public boolean excluirUsuario (int idUsuario) throws SQLException;
}
```

Meu Jdbc .dao class JdbcUsuarioDAO :

```
public class JdbcUsuarioDAO implements UsuarioDAO {

@SuppressWarnings("finally")
@Override
public Usuario buscarUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    Usuario usr = null;

    try {
        con = Conexao.getConnection();

        sql.append(" SELECT * FROM tb_usuario ");
        sql.append(" WHERE nome = ? and senha = ? ");
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        stmt.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
        stmt.setString(2, usuario.getSenha());

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id_usuario");
            String nomeUsuario = rs.getString("nome");
            String senha = rs.getString("senha");

            usr = new Usuario();
            usr.setId(id);
            usr.setNome(nomeUsuario);
            usr.setSenha(senha);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        return usr;
    }

}
```

Meu servlet ServletLogin:

```
    @WebServlet("/login")
public class ServletLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UsuarioDAO dao = new JdbcUsuarioDAO();

    public ServletLogin() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String redir = "/login.jsp";
        String msg = "";
        Usuario usuarioLogado = null;
        try {
            String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
            String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

            if (nome != null && senha != null) {

                Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
                usuario.setNome(nome);
                usuario.setSenha(senha);

                usuarioLogado = dao.buscarUsuario(usuario);

                if (usuarioLogado != null) {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("usuarioLogado",
                            usuarioLogado);
                    redir = "/index.jsp";
                } else {
                    msg = "Usuario Ou Senha Invalidos!";
                    redir = "/login.jsp";
                }
            } else {
                msg = "Informe O Usuario E Senha!";
                redir = "/login.jsp";
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            msg = "Erro ao efetuar o login!";
            redir = "/erro.jsp";
        } finally {
            request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(redir);
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Meu login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/clockcss.css"
    charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function runScript(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         validate();

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/Empresa/login" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="paginaLogin" value="s" /> 
        <div id="fundo_login">
            <div id="top_login">
                <div id="txt">Empresa</div>
            </div>
            <div id="alert">
                    <c:if test="${msg !=null}">
                        <font color="red">${msg}</font>
                    </c:if>
                </div>

            <div id="login">
                <div id="imguser"></div>
                <input type="text" maxlength="70" name="nome" placeholder="Nome"
                    required autofocus
                    style="width: 334px; height: 40px; margin-left: 30px; float: left; font-size: 20px; border-radius: 12px; outline: none; border: solid #fff" />
            </div>
            <div id="pass">
                <div id="imgpass"></div>
                <input type="password" maxlength="70" name="senha"
                    placeholder="Senha" required onkeypress="return runScript(event)"
                    style="width: 334px; height: 40px; margin-left: 29px; float: left; font-size: 20px; border-radius: 12px; outline: none; border: solid #fff" />
            </div>
            <div id="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" style="float: left; margin: 2px 5px;">
                <div id="txt1">Manter sessão</div>

            </div>
            <div id="botao_login">
                <input type="submit" value="Login"
                    style="width: 440px; height: 48px; background: #02a68b; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 8px; color: #fff; font-size: 18px; border: 1px solid #02a68b; margin: 20px 20px;" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ai está o que eu já fiz, eu estou pensando em criar uma class java "Nviel" no .model com :

-int : Nivel; -String : Descricao;

Assim chamar essa class no Usuario.java, depois não sei onde ir. Não sei como criar o MySQL, e não sei como chamar para as outras class e interface. Não sei se tenho que criar um javascript ou não.

Comment: Os níveis/papeís serão fixos ou sua aplicação vai gerenciar isso também?

Comment: Se me lembro direito, a recomendação do livro _Use a Cabeça! Servlets & JSP_ era de não fazer isso manualmente e sim deixar para o container gerenciar isso. Aí ele dava um exemplo usando o Tomcat. É o Tomcat que você está usando como servidor de aplicação? **P.S.:** Você pode usar servlet filters para interceptar requisições a servlets de acesso restrito e solicitar login ao usuário.

Comment: Cara, como o @Piovezan citou, use o j_security_check para autenticar os usuários. Outra coisa interessante que você pode usar são os Realms. Os realms do JBoss por exemplo são muito eficientes para este tipo de coisa. Reinventar a roda nunca é legal...

Comment: Miguel Cartagena - sim serão fixos. Piovezan - Sim estou usando um filter, mas meu filter só uso para ninguém acessar as outras paginas sem estar logado.

Comment: @Wagner Se você precisar responder aos comentários, é melhor fazer isso como um novo comentário (começando com uma referência a quem você quer responder, como eu fiz aqui). Dessa forma, a pessoa que comentou sabe que você respondeu a ela.

Comment: Por que você está escrevendo uma camada de autorização e autenticação na unha? O Java já possui o [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service), e vários Frameworks como [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/), [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) e [jGuard](http://jguard.xwiki.com/xwiki/bin/view/Doc/Overview). Todas essas opções irão permitir o uso de **perfis** e atender ao seu caso de uso de autenticação usando o banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir na classe usuario o atributo **perfil**. Quando o usuário criar uma conta, ele escolherá entre o perfil administrador, ou funcionário, por exemplo, logo ele será cadastrado com esse perfil. Na hora que ele logar, você salva na sessão o perfil dele e exibe apenas o conteúdo que pertence ao perfil dele fazendo um choose com jstl :

```
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.perfil == 'Administrador' }">
     Parabéns,você é o administrador!

    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    Que pena,você é apenas um usuario comun ç_ç!
    </c:otherwise>

    </c:choose>
```

[talvez esse post te ajude...](http://myblog-pedropazello.rhcloud.com/java/Cadastro-niveisdepermiss%C3%A3o-java/)

Comment: Nossa é isso mesmo obrigado cara!